# Getting SQL Server DateTime NULL into pandas

Tags: sql-server, pandas, adodbapi

I have a table in a SQL Server which contains, among other things, a `DateTime` column `From_UTC` and a `DateTime NULL` column `To_UTC`. I try to read it into a pandas `DataFrame`.

The non-NULL column comes in fine as a `datetime64`, but the other gets datatype `Object`.

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import adodbapi
conn = adodbapi.connect(...)
df = psql.read_frame("SELECT Unit, To_UTC, From_UTC, CategoryID FROM T_Alarm WHERE ...", con=conn)
df.dtypes

Unit                  object
To_UTC                object
From_UTC      datetime64[ns]
CategoryID             int64
dtype: object

df.To_UTC[0]
==> pywintypes.datetime(2011, 9, 6, 13, 51, 56)
```

If I include a `WHERE To_UTC IS NOT NULL` in my query, everything works fine.

I guess that a combination of adodbapi, the pywintypes.datetime objects, and the NULLs in the result prevents pandas from coercing into the right type?

I tried `df.convert_objects()`, but it didn't help.

**UPDATE**:

If I do `df.To_UTC = pandas.Series(df.To_UTC, dtype='datetime64[ns]')`
then I get the DataFrame I want.
But I would still like a more general solution so that I don't have to make this hack everywhere I do frame queries with nullable datetime results.

Comment: Can you show us how your data looks like? Especially the values of the DateTime Null Column?

Comment: The Datetime NULL column (To_UTC) is just a bunch of datetimes with a few NULLs mixed in. It is just the NULLs that cause the column to get dtype Object, since when I filter them out (in the SQL 'where' clause) I get the expected result.

Comment: What will a NULL in the data "mean" semantically for your code? Could you possible replace the NULLs with a minimum date value or similar?

Comment: No, this table is used by a lot of other code (mostly C#), I am just doing some data analysis on it from Python, so I'm not in a position to change the semantics / data structure.
The rows of the table denote a kind of alarms with begin and end times. Alarms that are still open will have only From_UTC set, while To_UTC will be NULL. When the alarm closes, the To_UTC will be set.

Comment: The NULL values should translate to a NaT value in Pandas. This is what I get with my workaround seen under the "UPDATE:" heading